# How find substring with regular expression

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have a sting "some text #texttext some other text #texttagtext". I need get all words with '#' symbol. If there are some ## or more symbols together, I need to replace them with one symbol '#'. Could any one help me with regular expression ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post valid input,expected output,attempts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?<=^|\s)#+(?=\S+)
```

Replacement string:

```
#
```

In objective-c, you need to escape backslash one more time.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/39)

To find all the words that starts with `#`

```
(?<=^|\s)#\S+
```

`\S+` would match any non-space character one or more times.

OR

```
(?<=^|\s)#\w+
```

`\w+` Match any word character one or more times.

To find all the words that starts with one or more `#`

```
(?<=^|\s)#+\S+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I also need to fing all words with '#' symbol. In my case it should be '#texttext' and '#texttagtext' words. Than I will do some logic with this words (will change color of them)